# Need to make a servlet class default in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have tried previous methods mentioned in other answers but still http://localhost:8080/InterConnect/ is showing 404 error. 
whereas http://localhost:8080/InterConnect/servlet/HomePageServlet page is running smoothly.

> web.xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<!-- Define servlets that are included in the example application -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>HomePageServlet</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SignInServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SignUpServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/SignInServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>SignUpServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/servlet/SignUpServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/servlet/HomePageServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you list what other answers you have tried.

Comment: Using <lead-on-start> tag with a value, but this is also not working. And <welcome-file-list>tag

Comment: Have you tried this for the  `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` for the HomePageServlet servlet-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browser requests `http://localhost:8080/InterConnect/`, assuming `InterConnect` is the context path, and given that you have declared `<welcome-file>HomePageServlet</welcome-file>`, the servlet container will look to see if a servlet mapping exists for `/HomePageServlet`.

You don't have a mapping for `/HomePageServlet`, only one for `/servlet/HomePageServlet`, so the web server returns 404 (Not found).

Try `<welcome-file>servlet/HomePageServlet</welcome-file>` to see if that works, or change servlet mapping to `/HomePageServlet`.